# Replacing a pendant light (with a loop connectors in rose) with a LED light without. In the UK

Tags: light-fixture

I want to replace a pendant light/ceiling rose with a loop, with an LED light that doesn't have a loop connector in it.

Current connector in the rose:
[image]

Light I want to fit:
[image]

From the 2nd picture you can see a supplied connector, to be used for connecting the new light to the outside (black) wires. Can I just use another connector for the red wire loop, and have them sitting in the new light's cavity too? If so, any preference of type/material etc?

Comment: can you keep the old connector or is it too too big or too damaged?

Comment: I hadn't really considered that! It's not damaged. It clips into the existing rose. I'll try that. Thanks Jasen

Comment: Pretty sure your new lighting is based on Light Emitting Diode (LED) technology, not Liquid Crystal Display (LCD) technology. :)

Comment: You can use any connector to make the connections shown in the first picture, adding your new light as required.  You don't have to use its supplied one or your old one.  Your challenge will be getting all those wires and connections into the shallow space available in the new light.  Does it have a backing plate with some extra space?

Answer (score 2):

If you need it smaller, just buy a strip of 5A terminal block [50p B&Q]

[image]

You can chop it how you like - one 3-piece chunk, or even individuals - so long as you only chop at the appropriate inter-connector points. No insulating tape required.
Get the bare ends into the block better than your original, if you can. That has definite hints of "well, no-one will see that."

The other upside, is if someone needs to go back in there in another 20 years, the plastic won't have perished. I wouldn't give that original 20 years' more life before it starts to crumble.

BTW, is their supplied block a push-fit, or maybe spring/squeeze-fit? Hard to tell. If it is, just throw it away.

Answer (score 0):

Nice thing about Wago 221 is they're only 7mm thick so they fit in tight spaces. Just measure the available space behind your LED light.

[image]

Comment: That's the kind of thing I'd avoid like the plague, same as the one in the OP's photo. Over-complex, will probably go brittle over time & in 20 years when the next poor DIYer tries to unclip it, the lever will break clean off. It's a wheel that doesn't need re-inventing.

Comment: They're more reliable, safer and easier to use than the screw terminal blocks.

Comment: In my years, I've come across more 'clever' devices left to crumble behind old electrics than I'd care to recall. No doubt most of those would have carried the same manufacturer's claim when new, too. I can't refute the claim, only time will tell, but we know for certain a bit of regular terminal block will be exactly the same in 20 years as it is now.

Comment: i once had to change out 4,000 T4 tubes & fittings, across 80 sites, that had perished to almost dust [all without knocking the power off]. That was the single worst *"it'll last a lifetime"* experience, but there have been many others ;)

Comment: I understand lol, always shiny new bullshit like compact fluorescent "last 10000 hours" that died every 6 months like clockwork. But these really work, all new construction here has been using these for decades without trouble. Good quality brands like Wago just work. As usual there are garbage quality knockoffs that will fall apart. On the other hand I've seen quite a few of the screw terminal blocks where the screws loosen over time, bad contacts, etc.

Comment: Ah, OK - it's not a structure I was aware of. I see you can get them in the UK, from 'proper' builder's merchants not just DIY stores, but I've never used them & didn't know they have a good history in the US. I did at one time make quite a good living out of regularly replacing 'clever' ideas across a wide range of retail stores where they would get a proper beating at the hands of customers, or had been left to perish in fittings that had been there since Noah was worried it might rain ;)) It makes me wary of the new-fangled on occasion.

Comment: I'm French ;) I don't know about the US, they'll probably hang on to their wire nuts for another century or two lol. But hey it works. If you're interested in trying, the ones for solid wire [don't have a lever](https://www.123elec.com/wago-pot-de-100-mini-bornes-de-connexion-3-fils-s2273.html) because you just push the wire in ; the ones with lever are for stranded wire that is too soft to push in. Also convenient for temporary stuff.

Comment: wago connectors can handle more current than 12AWG wire, dinky screw terminals can't. Not that that matters in an LED light, but you should be aware they are about as good as it gets for terminals.

Comment: @dandavis - We don't measure cables or terminals in 'AWG' or even 'dinkyness' they're sold in 'amp rating'. So long as one matches the other, it will last a lifetime.